# Custom RSS Feed Overwrites Permalink

Tags: rss

I'm trying to setup a custom RSS feed for attachments with a meta field. I succeeded in making the feed, however it's now overwriting the actual site content.

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_feed' );
function add_custom_feed() {
  add_feed( 'photos', 'render_photos_feed');
}
function render_photos_feed() {
  //WP_Query for attachment
  get_template_part( 'rss', 'photos' );
}
```

I have a poor understanding of where exactly a url is created here. What I'm expecting is `example.com/photos/feed` or `example.com/feed/photos`. I'm getting `example.com/feed/photos` but then also `example.com/photos`, which is where the Page that displays my photos exists. I can flush permalinks and turn off the action for this feed and render my page, but when it's online, I can see on the Photos page that its permalinked to `photos-2`. I can't find any documentation online about why that happens.

I really don't want to create a CPT for these, the workflow of adding a checkbox was really easy & reduces noise on the backend and the WP Query works. Secondarily, I also am wondering if it's possible to change the main feed to be posts & photos. I can't just hijack the feed WP_Query because its an OR logic (get posts or attachment w/ meta value). Any thoughts there are welcome too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `feed/photos` with `add_feed`. This rule will prevent the overwrite permalinks issue. Change your function like below and flush rewrite rules.

```php
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_feed' );
function add_custom_feed() {
  add_feed( 'feed/photos', 'render_photos_feed');
}
function render_photos_feed() {
  //WP_Query for attachment
  header("Content-type: text/xml"); // Added for XML output
  get_template_part( 'rss', 'photos' );
}
```

Comment: Great, so that works to get `feed/photos` as stated. Would you expect that link as standard for syndicating my content?

Comment: The `feed` is the standard way to distribute your content. Also, you can use `http://www.yoursite.com/feed/?post_type=book&genre=romance` like links in WordPress for CPT's or taxonomies. But this way could be easy to remember and use. So, np for me :)

Comment: Cool, thanks. Would you have any tips for merging my feeds?

Comment: Into one feed link? You can try this.
```php
function myfeed_request($qv) {
    if (isset($qv['feed']) && !isset($qv['post_type']))
        $qv['post_type'] = array('post', 'story', 'books', 'movies');
    return $qv;
}
add_filter('request', 'myfeed_request');
```

Comment: Oh thanks, but I don't think that works for me.

I have a `posts` feed, and then this feed you helped me with is `attachment`, *with a meta value*. So, I need OR logic, posts OR attachments w/ a meta val.